How to apply different width policies to columns in a HTML/CSS table?
I want columns 1, 2, and 3 to fit their content, while column 4 should display an ellipsis if the content overflows. Currently, column 4 has an ellipsis, but columns 1, 2, and 3 are taking up more space than their content requires.
The second table is an example of the desired table appearance. The column widths are for illustrative purposes only. Please note the following:
1- The table is contained within a 500px-wide div.
2- Text wrapping is disabled, ensuring consistent row heights.
3- CSS adjustments can be freely made to achieve the intended look.


  .table-container {
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    table {
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }

    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      text-align: left;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    td:nth-child(4) {
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      width: 1%;
      max-width: none;
    }
 Current code:
  <br>
  <div style="width: 500px; background-color: #f0f0f0; padding: 10px;">
   <div class="table-container">
      <table>
        <tbody><tr>
          <th>H1</th>
          <th>H2</th>
          <th>H3</th>
          <th>H4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:5px;">Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Lorem</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody></table>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>  
Desired result:

<div style="width: 500px; background-color: #f0f0f0; padding: 10px;">
   <div class="table-container">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:90px;">H1</th>
          <th style="width:35px;">H2</th>
          <th style="width:48px;">H3</th>
          <th>H4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td >Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Wo</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. </td>
        </tr>
                 <tr>
          <td >Lorem</td>
          <td>2222</td>
          <td>Ist</td>
          <td>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque. </td>
        </tr>
                 <tr>
          <td >Ipsum</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Lorem</td>
          <td>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit. </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>



Here is the code:
I tried the below without success.
td:nth-child(1), th:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(3), th:nth-child(3) {
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

Since the content of the table is unpredictable, setting fixed widths for columns (like width: 200px;) isn't suitable. The ideal approach is to dynamically adjust column widths based on their content.
Thank you!

Have you read about table-layout: fixed;?

When you set the table-layout property to fixed the cells will be fixed.  To adapt them to the content, you have to set it to auto. But when you do it, the setup for the ellipsis doesn't work. To fix it you can just add display:block; to it but then you have to specifically set the width of that cell in px. I tried using flexbox. It works but then you have a hard time aligning the the cells of each column without setting specific widths for each. So just choose your poison basically... I don't work very often with tables so I cannot help much. Hope this at least guides you a bit :)

Please edit your post to more precisely describe your desired result. Do you want the width of the table to expand and contract to fit the contents, or do you want the width of the table to match the width of the viewport? If your answer is the second one, how do you want any leftover space distributed?  And what if the viewport is narrow so that all the data won't fit on the screen at once? And how is the result of styling your table with table-layout: auto different from your desired result?

@SaraFreitas thank you. Using Flexbox offers flexibility but in this case alignment can be challenging without specific widths...

@BrettDonald I apologise for the initial lack of clarity. I just added more details and an example to provide a more precise description of my desired table behavior.

I have tried several methods using CSS, but they didn't work. If the first three columns take auto width, then the fourth column doesn't take the desired effect and vice versa.
So, here is a refined approach using JavaScript to achieve the desired output. What I have done is apply the CSS for the fourth column using JS, and that's it.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Table</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>

  <style>
    .table-container {
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    table {
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      text-align: left;
    }

    th:nth-child(1),
    th:nth-child(2),
    th:nth-child(3),
    td:nth-child(1),
    td:nth-child(2),
    td:nth-child(3) {
      width: auto;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="table-container">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>H1</th>
          <th>H2</th>
          <th>H3</th>
          <th>H4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            consequuntur illo officia
          </td>
          <td>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati
            totam architecto laborum culpa iste? Vero praesentium nostrum ullam,
          </td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor,</td>
          <td>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique
            laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Similique laborum
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      const fourthColCells = document.querySelectorAll(
        'th:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(4)'
      );
      fourthColCells.forEach(cell => {
        cell.style.width = '150px';
        cell.style.maxWidth = '150px';
        cell.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        cell.style.textOverflow = 'ellipsis';
        cell.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>

Output:

NOTE: Please carefully review the CSS applied. You might need to make slight adjustments to your existing CSS for this code to take effect.

Thank you for pointing this out. There's an issue with the width of the 4th column. In your JavaScript code, setting a fixed width (
cell.style.width = '150px') for the column can cause problems when other column widths change. This may prevent the table from fully utilising the available width of the main div. That's the concern...
Also have a look at the example I just put above, please.

@PHITON I think what you desire is not possible with simple HTML and CSS because if you will use overflow-y: auto; for .table-container with white-space: nowrap; then it will always display whole content with overflow. As much I got your problem, you wish to display first three column's content without wrap and forth column with ellipsis. But I think it is not possible as I mentioned earlier. So, you can set a limit for forth column using JS that if the text of forth column has more then 10 characters then trim that and add 3 dots at the end.

@PHITON if you get my point then let me know and I'll update my answer to help you out.

Thanks for your input! You know, the tricky part here is that we can't really predict how wide those columns are going to be. We've got the overall table size locked in, but those columns could be all over the place. That's why just chopping off the last column after a certain number of characters won't always look right.
It's a bummer because we're dealing with more and more complex data these days, and we need a solution that can handle anything we throw at it.

I remember trying a similar workaround for a project almost 4 years ago, but I was hoping that by now HTML and CSS would have evolved to handle this kind of thing more gracefully! :'|
